# TensorFlow inference using saved model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to TensorFlow 2.3.1 and trying to figure out how inference is done. After loading a saved model, I want to pass a tensor with only ones to make sure the model outputs what we expect. For example...

```
import tensorflow as tf

resnet18_tf = tf.saved_model.load("resnet18.tf")
x_tf = tf.ones((1,3,224,224), tf.float32)

resnet18_tf(x_tf)
```

However, the code above results in the following error...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-33fa05a7412b> in <module>
      4 x_tf = tf.ones((1,3,224,224), tf.float32)
      5 
----> 6 resnet18_tf(x_tf)

ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
  Positional arguments (1 total):
    * Tensor("None_0:0", shape=(1, 3, 224, 224), dtype=float32)
  Keyword arguments: {}

Expected these arguments to match one of the following 1 option(s):

Option 1:
  Positional arguments (0 total):
    * 
  Keyword arguments: {'input': TensorSpec(shape=(1, 3, 224, 224), dtype=tf.float32, name='input')}
```

I am pretty sure the shape is right, but I am struggling to interpret this error message. How do you make a TensorSpec input to resolve this error?

Comment: maybe try passing it as a keyword argument? `resnet18_tf(input=x_tf)`

Comment: Wow, that did the trick... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message

```
Expected these arguments to match one of the following 1 option(s):

Option 1:
  Positional arguments (0 total):
    * 
  Keyword arguments: {'input': TensorSpec(shape=(1, 3, 224, 224), dtype=tf.float32, name='input')}
```

suggests that the function is expecting keyword arguments and no positional arguments. The dictionary indicates that the keyword is `input`.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

resnet18_tf = tf.saved_model.load("resnet18.tf")
x_tf = tf.ones((1,3,224,224), tf.float32)

resnet18_tf(input=x_tf)
```